# Как обработать нажатие на элемент листбокса

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

У меня есть листбокс со списком файлов находящихся в определённой директории.

```
from tkinter import *
lo=Tk()
los=Listbox(lo)
los.pack()
list40=os.listdir()
for i in list40:
   los.insert(0,i)
lo.mainloop()
```

И мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на название файла выводилось его название.

Comment: Используйте метод bind() для обработки события "нажатие". Варианты нажатий вы не привели (это может быть нажатие клавиши или нажатие левой кнопки мыши).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
import os

lo=Tk()
los=Listbox(lo)
los.pack()
list40=os.listdir()
for i in list40:
    los.insert(0,i)


def on_select(event):
    # los.curselection() - получение индекса выделенного элемента
    # los.get() - получение элемента по его индексу
    print(los.get(los.curselection()))


# Привязка к событию выделения элемента списка
los.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_select)


lo.mainloop()
```